# d3 refocusable tree Chart in R

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js

**Background:**
I am new to both R and Javascript, and recently I came across an request to create a chart in R using D3. I have decent understanding of R but javascript is almost alien to me.We are trying to replicate the below chart in R using r2d3 library.

**Chart Link**
https://codepen.io/mikefab/full/IDdts

The link above shows the Chart and the Javascript & CSS behind it. The data is being prepared in the Javascript. I created a jason file for the data and saved the Javascript as "***rtree.js***" and CSS as "***rtree.css***" file and a separate dependencies file "***jquery1.js***" from the link (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js) tried to use it in the r2d3 function in r. The code is below

```
library(r2d3)
r2d3(data=read_json("flare.json"), d3_version = 3, script = 
 "rtree.js",css="rtree.css",dependencies = "jquery1.js",viewer = "internal")
```

I am constantly getting the error

```
Error: Cannot set property 'x0' of undefined in (rtree.js#221:4)
TypeError: Cannot set property 'x0' of undefined
at r2d3-script-783:226:11
```

I have done a lot of research online, and the only thing i found out that this javascript code is correct and working, but when I am trying to plug into R, I am getting this issue.

It will be a great help if the community here can help me in identifying what I am missing or doing incorrectly and also show me the right path forward.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1 : Adding the flare.jason, rtree.js and rtree.css code below**

**flare.json**

```
{
"name": "flare",
"children": [
{
"name": "analytics",
"children": [
{
"name": "cluster",
"children": [
{"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
{"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
{"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
{"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
]
},
{
"name": "graph",
"children": [
{"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
{"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
{"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
{"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
{"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
]
},
{
"name": "optimization",
"children": [
{"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
]
}
]
},
{
"name": "animate",
"children": [
{"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
{"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
{
"name": "interpolate",
"children": [
{"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
{"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
{"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
{"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
{"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
{"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
{"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
{"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
{"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
]
},
{"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
{"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
{"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
{"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
{"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
{"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
{"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
{"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
{"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
]
},
{
"name": "data",
"children": [
{
"name": "converters",
"children": [
{"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
{"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
{"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
{"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
{"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
]
},
{"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
{"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
{"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
{"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
{"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
{"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
]
},
{
"name": "display",
"children": [
{"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
{"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
{"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
{"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
]
},
{
"name": "flex",
"children": [
{"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
]
},
{
"name": "physics",
"children": [
{"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
{"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
{"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
{"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
{"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
{"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
{"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
{"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
]
},
{
"name": "query",
"children": [
{"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
{"name": "And", "size": 1027},
{"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
{"name": "Average", "size": 891},
{"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
{"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
{"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
{"name": "Count", "size": 781},
{"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
{"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
{"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
{"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
{"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
{"name": "If", "size": 2732},
{"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
{"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
{"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
{"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
{
"name": "methods",
"children": [
{"name": "add", "size": 593},
{"name": "and", "size": 330},
{"name": "average", "size": 287},
{"name": "count", "size": 277},
{"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
{"name": "div", "size": 595},
{"name": "eq", "size": 594},
{"name": "fn", "size": 460},
{"name": "gt", "size": 603},
{"name": "gte", "size": 625},
{"name": "iff", "size": 748},
{"name": "isa", "size": 461},
{"name": "lt", "size": 597},
{"name": "lte", "size": 619},
{"name": "max", "size": 283},
{"name": "min", "size": 283},
{"name": "mod", "size": 591},
{"name": "mul", "size": 603},
{"name": "neq", "size": 599},
{"name": "not", "size": 386},
{"name": "or", "size": 323},
{"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
{"name": "range", "size": 772},
{"name": "select", "size": 296},
{"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
{"name": "sub", "size": 600},
{"name": "sum", "size": 280},
{"name": "update", "size": 307},
{"name": "variance", "size": 335},
{"name": "where", "size": 299},
{"name": "xor", "size": 354},
{"name": "_", "size": 264}
]
},
{"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
{"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
{"name": "Or", "size": 970},
{"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
{"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
{"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
{"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
{"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
{"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
{"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
]
},
{
"name": "scale",
"children": [
{"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
{"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
{"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
{"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
{"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
{"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
{"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
{"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
{"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
{"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
]
},
{
"name": "util",
"children": [
{"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
{"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
{"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
{"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
{"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
{"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
{
"name": "heap",
"children": [
{"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
{"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
]
},
{"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
{"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
{"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
{
"name": "math",
"children": [
{"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
{"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
{"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
]
},
{"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
{"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
{
"name": "palette",
"children": [
{"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
{"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
{"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
{"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
]
},
{"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
{"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
{"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
{"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
{"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
]
},
{
"name": "vis",
"children": [
{
"name": "axis",
"children": [
{"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
{"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
{"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
{"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
{"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
]
},
{
"name": "controls",
"children": [
{"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
{"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
{"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
{"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
{"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
{"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
{"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
{"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
{"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
{"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
{"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
]
},
{
"name": "data",
"children": [
{"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
{"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
{"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
{"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
{"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
{
"name": "render",
"children": [
{"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
{"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
{"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
{"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
]
},
{"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
{"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
{"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
]
},
{
"name": "events",
"children": [
{"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
{"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
{"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
{"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
]
},
{
"name": "legend",
"children": [
{"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
{"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
{"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
]
},
{
"name": "operator",
"children": [
{
"name": "distortion",
"children": [
{"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
{"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
{"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
]
},
{
"name": "encoder",
"children": [
{"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
{"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
{"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
{"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
{"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
]
},
{
"name": "filter",
"children": [
{"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
{"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
{"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
]
},
{"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
{
"name": "label",
"children": [
{"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
{"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
{"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
]
},
{
"name": "layout",
"children": [
{"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
{"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
{"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
{"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
{"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
{"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
{"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
{"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
{"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
{"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
{"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
{"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
{"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
{"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
{"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
]
},
{"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
{"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
{"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
{"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
{"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
]
},
{"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
]
}
]
}
```

**rtree.js**

```
(function() {
var construct_generations, diagonal, diameter, div, duration, height, i, radius, reconstruct_ancestors, reform_focus, root, store_and_update, svg, tree, treeData, update, zoom;

treeData = data;
tree = d3.layout.tree().size([360, radius - 120]);


// ************** Generate the tree diagram *****************
window.current_nodes = [];

update = function(source) {
var link, links, node, nodeEnter, nodeExit, nodeUpdate, nodes;
// Compute the new tree layout.
nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
links = tree.links(nodes);
// Normalize for fixed-depth.
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
return d.y = d.depth * 80;
});
// Update the nodes…
node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
});
// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node").attr("transform", function(d) {}, {}, "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")").on("mouseover", function(d) {}).on("click", function(d) {
var clicked_same_node;
clicked_same_node = false;
if (window.current_nodes.length > 0) {
if (d.id === window.current_nodes[window.current_nodes.length - 1][0].id) {
clicked_same_node = true;
d3.event.stopPropagation();
}
}
if (!clicked_same_node) {
return store_and_update(d);
}
});
nodeEnter.append("circle").attr("r", 1e-6).style("fill", function(d) {
if (d._children) {
return "lightsteelblue";
} else {
return "#fff";
}
});
nodeEnter.append("text").attr("dy", ".31em").attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
if (d.x < 180) {
return "start";
} else {
return "end";
}
}).attr("transform", function(d) {
if (d.x < 180) {
return "translate(8)";
} else {
return "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
}
}).text(function(d) {
return d.name;
});
// Transition nodes to their new position.
nodeUpdate = node.transition().duration(duration).attr("transform", function(d) {
return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
});
nodeUpdate.select("circle").attr("r", 10).style("fill", function(d) {
if (d._children) {
return "black";
} else {
return "black";
}
});
nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1).attr("dy", ".31em").attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
if (d.x < 180) {
return "start";
} else {
return "end";
}
}).attr("transform", function(d) {
if (d.x < 180) {
return "translate(8)";
} else {
return "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
}
});
// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
nodeExit = node.exit().transition().duration(duration).attr("transform", function(d) {
return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
}).remove();
nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 1e-6);
nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
// Update the links…
link = svg.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function(d) {
return d.target.id;
});
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("path", "g").attr("class", "link").attr("d", function(d) {
var o;
o = {
x: source.x0,
y: source.y0
};
return diagonal({
source: o,
target: o
});
});
// Transition links to their new position.
link.transition().duration(duration).attr("d", diagonal);
// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
link.exit().transition().duration(duration).attr("d", function(d) {
var o;
o = {
x: source.x,
y: source.y
};
return diagonal({
source: o,
target: o
});
}).remove();
// Stash the old positions for transition.
return nodes.forEach(function(d) {
d.x0= d.x;
return d.y0 = d.y;
});
};

construct_generations = function(d) {
var c, generations;
c = d; // make a clone of d.
generations = []; // Array for each ancestors children. Will reconstruct later on body click
while (c.parent) {
generations.push(c.parent.children);
c = c.parent;
}
return generations;
};

reform_focus = function() {
var count, d, set;
if (window.current_nodes.length > 0) {
set = window.current_nodes.pop();
d = set[0];
count = 0;
d.parent._children = set[1];
if (d.parent._children) {
while (d.parent) {
d.parent.children = set[1][count];
count++;
d = d.parent;
}
return update(d);
}
}
};

store_and_update = function(d) {
window.current_nodes.push([d, construct_generations(d)]);
while (d.parent) {
// Back up original tree
d.parent._children = d.parent.children;
// Filter out non line of site children
d.parent.children = [
_.find(d.parent.children,
function(e) {
return e.name === d.name;
})
];
d = d.parent;
}
d3.event.stopPropagation();
return update(d);
};

reconstruct_ancestors = function(n, generations) {
var count;
count = generations.length - 1;
while (n.parent) {
n.parent.children = generations[count];
count -= 1;
n = n.parent;
}
return n;
};

$("body").click(function() {
return reform_focus();
});

diameter = 720;

height = diameter - 150;

radius = diameter / 2;

root = void 0;


i = 0;

duration = 2000;

diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial().projection(function(d) {
return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
});

zoom = function() {
return svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
};

div = d3.select("#focus");

svg = div.insert("svg").attr("viewbox", "0 0 " + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2).attr("width", "900px").attr("height", "100%").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")").append("g").call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom));

root = treeData[0];

root.x0 = height/2;

root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

}).call(this);
```

**rtree.css**

```
.node {cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the files `flare.json` and `rtree.js`, so that we can reproduce ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I can not attach the file or provide a download link. But I have provided the underlying code for each of the file. You can simply save them to a notepad and save it as 'flare.jason' and rtree.js respectively. And hopefully, you will be able to reproduce the same scenario

Comment: Nice, it's good like this. Now I'm not sure I'm able to help. I'm taking a look now.

Comment: `d3` is beyond my skills. I would use the `networkD3` package (function `radialNetwork`). I have to go now, give it a try and if you don't manage I'll try to help when I'll be back. This is what I get with `networkD3`: https://imgur.com/X1nQsMg

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks. It looks exactly what I am looking for but is it refocusable? i.e. when you click on a node, that becomes the center, just like https://codepen.io/mikefab/full/IDdts .
Also, can you share your script?

Comment: Looks like nothing happens when one clicks on a node. The script is short: `library(networkD3)` `dat <- jsonlite::read_json("flare.json")` `radialNetwork(List = dat, fontSize = 10, opacity = 0.9)`

Comment: Also you might be interested in [this package](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/radialNetworkR)

Comment: There's another version of `networkD3` which offers more possibilities. `devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/networkD3@feature/d3.chart.layout")` `hierNetwork(dat, type = "tree.radial", collapsible = TRUE)` I've found that [here](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/1/23/week-03-more-network-layouts)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you so much for your help! You have definitely shown me the right direction and some really awesome resources. I will definitely ask you again if i further run into any troubles.
Thanks a lot for your help!